# Java fx start function error

Tags: javafx

Hello I am having difficulties to determine the error. I created the main class which starts java fx application. When this class is inside Default package everything works but when I create this class in my package it gives this error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1567581361.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2438)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
at Address.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:65)
at Address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/1492735582.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1190035432.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/223236686.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1685538367.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception running application Address.MainApp
C:\Users\GHOST\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fx tutorial training\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\GHOST\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fx tutorial training\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example exhibiting this problem.

Comment: I  think that is an error about path. I have three packages core, model, view. Main is in core but path to access a fxml in view is"viev/".  But how to make view child of core?

Comment: I solved it. Thank you anyway